# Electron freezes when executing native NodeJS module

Tags: c++, node.js, electron, node-modules

I have some C++ code written as a NodeJS native module. The function to initialize everything opens some threads which have infinite while loops, which need to be run until the program closes. In command line everything works just fine, but when I call the function in electron, it hangs. Is there any way to call C++ from electron that isn't blocking?

I believe the main issue is the fact that the initialize function doesn't ever return unless the app is quit, and that makes electron angy (no typo).

Comment: `In command line everything works just fine` does not mean that the code is logically correct. It might just work in that situation, but there could still be a bug/false assumption in your thread related code that will cause a deadlock or something like that.

Comment: I've tested the threaded code in a standalone C++ program. I've only made a few modifications so that it can be called from a Node app.

Comment: The paragraph you added is crucial information. If you invoke the C++ from JavaScript and that C++ function does not return (blocks until the thread is finished)  then this indeed will cause electron to freeze. The function has to return and your thread has to run in the background.

Comment: So is there a way to start up threads that will allow the function to return? I'm currently using Thread.join()

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the soultion! Thanks @t.niese! Rather than using `Thread.join()`, which holds up the function until the app quits, I needed to use `Thread.detach()`, and make a function to clean everything up when done.